# How tor eplace substrings in a string with a new substring

Tags: arrays, c, string

Hi guys i'm a beginner at c

i'm trying to make a string_replace function(str,find,replace) , this function replaces all find substrings and replaces it 'replace' substring
this is the code i have right now , but i get a

```
heap-buffer-overflow
```

error and I'm not sure why
can anyone help?

```
void string_replace(char **str, const char *find, const char *replace) {
  int i, cnt = 0; 
  int newWlen = strlen(replace); 
  int oldWlen = strlen(find); 
  int len = strlen(*str);
  char *a = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));


  // Counting the number of times old word 
  // occur in the string 
  cnt = string_count(*str,find);




  a = realloc(a,((len + cnt * (newWlen - oldWlen) + 1)*sizeof(char))); 




  i = 0; 
  while (*str) 
  { 


    if (strstr(*str, find) == *str) 
    { 
      strcpy(&a[i], replace); 
      i += newWlen; 
      *str += oldWlen; 
    } 
    else
      a[i++] = **str++; 
  } 
  a[i] = '\0';
  *str = a;
  free(a);
}
```

Comment: `*str = a; free(a);` smells because what is pointed at by saved pointer is freed. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Below you have the functions

This one uses the same string to store the result (so it has to be big enough):

```
char *stringreplace(char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace)
{
    size_t needleLen = strlen(needle);
    size_t replaceLen = strlen(replace);
    char *wrk = haystack;
    char *end = haystack + strlen(haystack);



    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        memmove(wrk + replaceLen, wrk + needleLen, end - wrk + 1);
        memcpy(wrk, replace, replaceLen);
        wrk += replaceLen;
        end += replaceLen - needleLen;
    }
    return haystack;
}
```

This one is using dynamic allocation. Note that on many systems `malloc` and especially `realloc` are very expensive operation and it is often worth tto traverse the string twice and call only one malloc knowing the size of the resulting string.

```
char *dupstringreplace(const char *haystack, const char *needle, const char *replace)
{
    char *newhaystack = NULL;
    const char *wrk = haystack;
    char *newwrk;
    ssize_t occurences = 0;
    size_t needleLen = strlen(needle);
    size_t replaceLen = strlen(replace);

    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        occurences++;
        wrk += needleLen;
    }
    newhaystack = malloc(strlen(haystack) + occurences * ((ssize_t)replaceLen - (ssize_t)needleLen) + 1);
    wrk = haystack;
    newwrk = newhaystack;
    while((wrk = strstr(wrk, needle)))
    {
        memcpy(newwrk, haystack, wrk - haystack);
        newwrk += wrk - haystack;
        memcpy(newwrk, replace, replaceLen);
        newwrk += replaceLen;
        wrk += needleLen;
        haystack = wrk;
    }
    strcpy(newwrk, haystack);
    return newhaystack;
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/b4eyk_)

```
void *mymemcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    unsigned char *cdest = dest;
    unsigned char *csrc = src;
    while(len--) *cdest++ = *csrc++;
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Ii'm not allowed to use memcpy and am only allowed to use realloc and malloc, what can i change in my function to remove the error?

Comment: write missing functions yourself as an exercise. They are much more simple - as an example see memcpy

Comment: for your second function you have made a new array and returned that array, however, is there a way you can just use pointers in a void function like i did ?